# what is the type of the variable

Tags: python, soappy

I am a very newbie in Python I have the following code:

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL

fichier_wsdl = 'http://geocoder.us/dist/eg/clients/GeoCoder.wsdl'
wsdl = WSDL.Proxy(fichier_wsdl)
callInfo = wsdl.methods['geocode']
ss = wsdl.geocode('1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC.')
print(ss)
```

The result is:

```
IMPORT:  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
no schemaLocation attribute in import
<<class 'SOAPpy.Types.typedArrayType'> results at 21824752>: [<SOAPpy.Types.structType item at 21818984>: {'city': 'Washington', 'prefix': '', 'suffix': 'NW', 'zip': 20502, 'number': 1600, 'long': -77.037684, 'state': 'DC', 'street': 'Pennsylvania', 'lat': 38.898748, 'type': 'Ave'}]
```

and I try to understand what type has my ss variable (the print(type(ss)) get SOAPpy.Types.typedArrayType which is not very clear for me)?
And how to have a simple variable, for the city or the street?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reformat that output for readability:

```
<<class 'SOAPpy.Types.typedArrayType'> results at 21824752>:

[<SOAPpy.Types.structType item at 21818984>:
     {'city': 'Washington', 'prefix': '', 'suffix': 'NW', 'zip': 20502, 'number': 1600,
      'long': -77.037684, 'state': 'DC', 'street': 'Pennsylvania', 'lat': 38.898748,
      'type': 'Ave'
     }
 ]
```

It's telling you what type your variable is: `SOAPpy.Types.typedArrayType` ... try reading the SOAPpy docs to understand that (I'm a SOAPpy non-user, not even a newbie).

What you really want to know is how to use that result. Looks to me like if you do `answer_dict = ss[0]`, you can access the fields like this:

`print answer_dict['city']` should produce `Washington` etc

so you can do

```
city = answer_dict['city']
street = answer_dict['street']
# et cetera
```

Note that `ss` with the fancy type looks like it acts like a list ... if your query has multiple answers (check `len(ss)`), you will need to iterate over the list:

```
for answer_dict in ss:
    process_each_answer(answer_dict) # substitute your code here
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just do `type(variable name)`.

Comment: Yes... so my question was not very clear. The answer is :'SOAPpy.Types.typedArrayType' ans I don't know how to use it (I change my question to be more clear)

Comment: for future answers, you don't need to add a signature line.  You're name's already attached to the post :)